# How to populate custom attributes for custom cms components in /cms/pages OCC endpoint

Tags: spartacus-storefront

I have created a custom cms components that has a couple of custom attributes that I need to access in the spartacus storefront. in the API endpoint /cms/pages (PagesController) I just get a basic representation of this component, without the custom attributes.

```
               "uid" : "sofortComponent",
               "uuid" : "eyJpdGVtSWQiOiJzb2ZvcnRDb21wb25lbnQiLCJjYXRhbG9nSWQiOiJlbGVjdHJvbmljcy1zcGFDb250ZW50Q2F0YWxvZyIsImNhdGFsb2dWZXJzaW9uIjoiT25saW5lIn0=",
               "typeCode" : "***APMComponent",
               "modifiedtime" : "2020-11-24T13:02:05.847+01:00",
               "name" : "SOFORT @",
               "container" : "false",
               "media" : {
                  "code" : "sofort-icon",
                  "mime" : "image/png",
                  "url" : "/medias/?context=bWFzdGVyfGltYWdlc3wxNzU0fGltYWdlL3BuZ3xpbWFnZXMvaGVlL2hkMy84Nzk3MzAyOTE1MTAyLnBuZ3w4MzMxNmEzNTFhODBkYzEzYzVmNmUxZjgzNzI2MzU0MGI3MzJlNjg1ZWQzZjlhY2FjMWMxNDNkNDUyOTEzODQ4"
               }
            }, {
               "uid" : "creditCardComponent",
               "uuid" : "eyJpdGVtSWQiOiJjcmVkaXRDYXJkQ29tcG9uZW50IiwiY2F0YWxvZ0lkIjoiZWxlY3Ryb25pY3Mtc3BhQ29udGVudENhdGFsb2ciLCJjYXRhbG9nVmVyc2lvbiI6Ik9ubGluZSJ9",
               "typeCode" : "...",
               "modifiedtime" : "2020-11-23T14:03:28.472+01:00",
               "name" : "Credit Card",
               "container" : "false"
            },  ... ]
```

My component (sofortComponent) has an attribute that I want to populate, but I can't find any documentation on how to do this.

I've tried adding a populator to the `cmsRenderingCmsItemConverterCustomPopulators`, but that doesn't allow me to add complex attributes to the model (strings yes, but complicated items no..) Or maybe I am doing it wrong.

Can anyone guide me to the docs or an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fields exposed in the OCC api are driven by so-called pre-configured sets. While the default resources have pre-configured sets associated, you need to create your pre-configured sets for new types. This is documentation, see https://help.sap.com/viewer/9d346683b0084da2938be8a285c0c27a/1808/en-US/8c404c5886691014a48c88f4a49f9bf3.html

The pre-configured sets are provided for BASIC, DEFAULT and FULL sets. If you do not request a specific field mapping, the OCC mapping that is configured for DEFAULT will be used. You can however specify the field mapping in the request, either by using one of the pre-configured sets or by naming out specific fields. Or a combination of both, i.e. FULL pre-configured + customer fields that are not part of the pre-configured set.

In Spartacus you can configure the field mapping, by providing an endpoint configuration. This is documented at https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/connecting-to-other-systems/#configuring-endpoints. This means that even if you do not have pre-configured sets at all in the backend, you should still be able to request the data.

Comment: This is my request: /occ/v2/electronics-spa/cms/pages?fields=DEFAULT&pageType=ContentPage&pageLabelOrId=%2Fnot-found&lang=en&curr=USD. If I add the field (apmConfiguration) to the fields parameters, I get an error ```<errorList>
<errors>
<message>Incorrect field:'apmConfiguration'</message>
<type>ConversionError</type>
</errors>
</errorList>```

Comment: /occ/v2/electronics-spa/cms/pages?fields=DEFAULT,apmConfiguration&pageType=ContentPage&pageLabelOrId=%2Fcheckout%2Fpayment-details&lang=en&curr=USD

Comment: Hello, you can contact SmartEdit team for it. We need 2 converters/populators for complex attribute, one is from `model` to `data`, the other one is from `data` to `wsDTO`. `wcms` module is owned by SmartEdit team, please contact them for guide. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1. Did you try to configure Spartacus endpoints to ask for your new fields, i.e.  `backend.occ.endpoints.pages` =  `'cms/pages?fields=...'`? See https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/connecting-to-other-systems/#configuring-endpoints
2. You might also need to extend the class `OccCmsPageNormalizer` to map your new fields of the Occ model to the Spartacus UI model. See https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/connecting-to-other-systems/#extending-the-ui-model

Comment: hi, I don't yet get the attributes from OCC. Even when I set fields=FULL or fields=FULL,<myattributename>, I don't get the attribute in the <component>. So the issue is in OCC, but very much related to spartacus

Comment: Can you confirm that this custom attrubute doesn't come in the HTTP response, by inspecting Network request in browser dev tools?

Comment: I can confirm that the attribute is not in the HTTP response, @platonn.

Comment: Usually backend models are mapped to frontend models (almost) 1:1 in Spartacus Converters classes (for more about convertes, see docs  https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/connecting-to-other-systems/#convertor). But only now I noticed that `OccCmsPageNormalizer` contains a lot of custom mapping logic. And there is a chance that this logic doesn't copy all the backend component model's properties to the frontend model. Would you mind verifying that, please? You might want to extend `OccCmsPageNormalizer` and debug. If you find what needs fixing, please create a ticket in the Spartacus repo.